# How can I compile minix when I make changes in libraries

Tags: kernel, compiling, c, minix

I am looking for a way to compile minix. The `make hdboot` command seems to do nothing with the directories under `/usr/src/lib`. I changed only one `.c` file in syslib. Do I have to do `make world` for this ?